# How do i get the name of the clicked item of the ListView?

Tags: android, listview, toast, onitemclicklistener

How do I get the name of the clicked item of the `ListView` ?

```
public void addExercise(View view) {
        LayoutInflater mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
        final View exercises = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.exercises, null);
        final Spinner spinner = (Spinner) exercises.findViewById(R.id.sessionTypeSpinner);

        final ListView listView = (ListView) exercises.findViewById(R.id.listViewexercises);
        rowItems = new ArrayList<RowItem>();
        for (int i = 0; i < titles.length; i++) {
            RowItem item = new RowItem(images[i], titles[i], descriptions[i]);
            rowItems.add(item);
        }

        CustomListViewAdapter adapter2 = new CustomListViewAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
                R.layout.exercises_custom_row, rowItems);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter2);

        // ListView Item Click Listener
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {

                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Item " + (position + 1) + ": " + rowItems.get(position),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 0, 0);
                toast.show();

            }

        });


        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                switch (position) {
                    case 0:
                        final ListView listView = (ListView) exercises.findViewById(R.id.listViewexercises);
                        rowItems = new ArrayList<RowItem>();
                        for (int i = 0; i < titles.length; i++) {
                            RowItem item = new RowItem(images[i], titles[i], descriptions[i]);
                            rowItems.add(item);
                        }

                        CustomListViewAdapter adapter = new CustomListViewAdapter(getApplication(),
                                R.layout.exercises_custom_row, rowItems);
                        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

                        // ListView Item Click Listener
                        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                                    int position, long id) {

                                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                        "Item " + (position + 1) + ": " + rowItems.get(position),
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                                toast.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 0, 0);
                                toast.show();

                                int arme = workoutDBAO.addSession(workoutId, position);
                                Map newRow = new HashMap();
                                newRow.put("id", arme);
                                newRow.put("type", 10 + position);
                                sessionAdapter.add(newRow);


                            }

                        });
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        ListView listView1 = (ListView) exercises.findViewById(R.id.listViewexercises);
                        rowItems = new ArrayList<RowItem>();
                        for (int i = 0; i < titles1.length; i++) {
                            RowItem item = new RowItem(images[i], titles1[i], descriptions[i]);
                            rowItems.add(item);
                        }

                        CustomListViewAdapter adapter1 = new CustomListViewAdapter(getApplication(),
                                R.layout.exercises_custom_row, rowItems);
                        listView1.setAdapter(adapter1);

                        // ListView Item Click Listener
                        listView1.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                                    int position, long id) {

                                ArrayList<RowItem> title = rowItems;
                                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                        "Item " + (position + 1) + ": " + title.get(position),
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                                toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 0, 0);
                                toast.show();





                            }

                        });

                        break;

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });

        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setTitle(R.string.action_add_step)
                .setView(exercises)
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.dialog_ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                        int exerciseNr = spinner.getSelectedItemPosition();



                    }
                }).show(); //
    }

    //OnClick on Item that you created
    class ListViewItemClickHandler implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int i, long l) {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Item was clicked",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 0, 0);
            toast.show();

        }
    }
class SessionItemAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Map> {

        ArrayList<Map> values;
        Context context;

        SessionItemAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Map> values) {
            super(context, R.layout.session_list_layout_row, values);
            this.values = values;
            this.context = context;
        }


        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) parent.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.session_list_layout_row, parent, false);

            TextView tv = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.stepTime);
            final int rowId = (Integer) values.get(position).get("id");
            int beepStringId = getResources().getIdentifier("exercise_typ_" + values.get(position).get("type"), "string", getPackageName());

            rowView.setTag(rowId);

            tv.setText(getResources().getString(beepStringId));

            ImageButton deleteSession = (ImageButton) rowView.findViewById(R.id.session_item_del);
            deleteSession.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    /*if (!startStopToggle.isChecked()) {*/
                        sessionAdapter.remove(values.get(position));
                    sessionAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


                }
            });

            return rowView;
        }
```

I want to show it in the `Toast` that is in the `OnItemClick`method of the  *ListViewItemClickHandler* class.
So I think somehow there I must get the name of the clicked item to show it but I don't know how so please help me!

**Edit**

My RowItem class

```
public class RowItem {
    private int imageId;
    private String title;
    private String desc;

    public RowItem(int imageId, String title, String desc) {
        this.imageId = imageId;
        this.title = title;
        this.desc = desc;
    }

    public int getImageId() {
        return imageId;
    }

    public void setImageId(int imageId) {
        this.imageId = imageId;
    }

    public String getDesc() {
        return desc;
    }

    public void setDesc(String desc) {
        this.desc = desc;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return title + "\n" + desc;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is an Item's name?

Comment: show us the RowItem class please

Comment: I edited it, is it better now?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {

                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Item " + (position + 1) + ": " + rowItems.get(position).getTitle(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 0, 0);
                toast.show();

            }
```